# How to check if previous task is still running and stop/cancel it?

Tags: c#, taskfactory

I have a background task that I run in the following way.

This is in an attached behavior on a textbox text changed event.

What I would like is if the text is changed and then changed again, on the second change check if the previous task is still running, if so, stop it and continue with the latest one.

```
public class FindTextChangedBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.TextChanged += OnTextChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.TextChanged -= OnTextChanged;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    private void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var textBox = (sender as TextBox);
        if (textBox != null)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                //Do text search on object properties within a DataGrid
                //and populate temporary ObservableCollection with items.
                ClassPropTextSearch.init(itemType, columnBoundProperties);

                if (itemsSource != null)
                {
                    foreach (object o in itemsSource)
                    {
                        if (ClassPropTextSearch.Match(o, searchValue))
                        {
                            tempItems.Add(o);
                        }
                    }
                }

                //Copy temporary collection to UI bound ObservableCollection 
                //on UI thread
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => MyClass.Instance.SearchMarkers = tempItems));
            });
        }
    }
```

[EDIT] I have not tested this yet just a mockup of what might be.

```
CancellationTokenSource CancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

private void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
{
    var newCts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var oldCts = Interlocked.Exchange(ref this.CancellationTokenSource, newCts);

    if (oldCts != null)
    {
        oldCts.Cancel();
    }

    var cancellationToken = newCts.Token;

    var textBox = (sender as TextBox);
    if (textBox != null)
    {
        ObservableCollection<Object> tempItems = new ObservableCollection<Object>();
        var ui = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

        var search = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            ClassPropTextSearch.init(itemType, columnBoundProperties);

            if (itemsSource != null)
            {
                foreach (object o in itemsSource)
                {
                    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    if (ClassPropTextSearch.Match(o, searchValue))
                    {
                        tempItems.Add(o);
                    }
                }
            }
        }, cancellationToken);

        //Still to be considered.
        //If it gets to here and it is still updating the UI then 
        //what to do, upon SearchMarkers being set below do I cancel
        //or wait until it is done and continue to update again???
        var displaySearchResults = search.ContinueWith(resultTask =>
                     MyClass.Instance.SearchMarkers = tempItems,
                     CancellationToken.None,
                     TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion,
                     ui);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am a bit worried about you proposing trawling through "object properties within a DataGrid" on a non-UI thread - this may very well work as you're not *setting* any values from the background thread, but has a bit of a smell to it.

Ignoring that for now, let me propose the following solution:

```
private readonly SemaphoreSlim Mutex = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
private CancellationTokenSource CancellationTokenSource;

private void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
{
    var newCts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var oldCts = Interlocked.Exchange(ref this.CancellationTokenSource, newCts);

    if (oldCts != null)
    {
        oldCts.Cancel();
    }

    var cancellationToken = newCts.Token;

    var textBox = (sender as TextBox);
    if (textBox != null)
    {
        // Personally I would be capturing
        // TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
        // here and then scheduling a continuation using that (UI) scheduler.
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            // Ensure that only one thread can execute
            // the try body at any given time.
            this.Mutex.Wait(cancellationToken);

            try
            {
                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                RunSearch(cancellationToken);

                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                //Copy temporary collection to UI bound ObservableCollection 
                //on UI thread
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => MyClass.Instance.SearchMarkers = tempItems));
            }
            finally
            {
                this.Mutex.Release();
            }
        }, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Since I know now that you're targeting an `async`-aware framework, the above solution can be both simplified and enhanced.

I had to make numerous assumptions as to how "grid properties" are harvested and made an attempt to decouple that process (which in my mind should be running on the dispatcher thread) from the actual search (which I'm scheduling on the thread pool).

```
public class FindTextChangedBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.TextChanged += OnTextChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.TextChanged -= OnTextChanged;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    private CancellationTokenSource CancellationTokenSource;

    // We're a UI handler, hence async void.
    private async void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        // Assume that this always runs on the UI thread:
        // no thread safety when exchanging the CTS.
        if (this.CancellationTokenSource != null)
        {
            this.CancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        }

        this.CancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        var cancellationToken = this.CancellationTokenSource.Token;

        var textBox = (sender as TextBox);
        if (textBox != null)
        {
            try
            {
                // If your async work completes too quickly,
                // the dispatcher will be flooded with UI
                // update requests producing a laggy user
                // experience. We'll get around that by
                // introducing a slight delay (throttling)
                // before going ahead and performing any work.
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100), cancellationToken);

                // Reduce TaskCanceledExceptions.
                // This is async void, so we'll just
                // exit the method instead of throwing.

                // IMPORTANT: in order to guarantee that async
                // requests are executed in correct order
                // and respond to cancellation appropriately,
                // you need to perform this check after every await.
                // THIS is the reason we no longer need the Semaphore.
                if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) return;

                // Harvest the object properties within the DataGrid.
                // We're still on the UI thread, so this is the
                // right place to do so.
                IEnumerable<GridProperty> interestingProperties = this
                    .GetInterestingProperties()
                    .ToArray(); // Redundant if GetInterestingProperties returns a
                                // list, array or similar materialised IEnumerable.

                // This appears to be CPU-bound, so Task.Run is appropriate.
                ObservableCollection<object> tempItems = await Task.Run(
                    () => this.ResolveSearchMarkers(interestingProperties, cancellationToken)
                );

                // Do not forget this.
                if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) return;

                // We've run to completion meaning that
                // OnTextChanged has not been called again.
                // Time to update the UI.
                MyClass.Instance.SearchMarkers = tempItems;
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                // Expected.
                // Can still be thrown by Task.Delay for example.
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // This is a really, really unexpected exception.
                // Do what makes sense: log it, invalidate some
                // state, tear things down if necessary.
            }
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<GridProperty> GetInterestingProperties()
    {
        // Be sure to return a materialised IEnumerable,
        // i.e. array, list, collection.
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<object> ResolveSearchMarkersAsync(
        IEnumerable<GridProperty> interestingProperties, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var tempItems = new ObservableCollection<object>();

        //Do text search on object properties within a DataGrid
        //and populate temporary ObservableCollection with items.
        foreach (var o in interestingProperties)
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            if (ClassPropTextSearch.Match(o, searchValue))
            {
                tempItems.Add(o);
            }
        }

        return tempItems;
    }
}
```

Comment: Definitely targeting 4.5 up. Just running through what you have suggested.

Comment: If that's the case there are some pretty substantial improvements that can be made to the above code. Simpler/bettet exception handling, throttling (my bet is that you'll find your UI quite laggy in the current implementation despite the asynchrony), and the like. I'll edit my answer with some additional propositions when I get a free minute.

Comment: Appreciate it! Also added to my example above, showing what's in the current task.

Comment: Agree about the comment: scheduling a continuation using that (UI) scheduler

Comment: Made an edit in the question above showing a mockup.

Comment: @Hank, it's an improvement, but you'll struggle to enhance it moving forward (if you suddenly need to integrate one or more additional async operation, for instance, the continuation scheduling will become very complicated very quickly) unless you adopt async/await. You're also leaving out exception handling simply swallowing exceptions by not executing the continuation. I've updated the answer with an async/await example (apologies if I missed the mark with some of the assumptions).

Comment: That is working really nicely thankyou, just put a try/catch in the ResolveSearchMarkersAsync to handle ThrowIfCancellationRequested. This is a first for me providing search functionality on DataGrid items. I would be very interested to hear from someone with experience on how they would implement the same. Would you be interested in such discussion if I opened a new question? I will place a screenshot on what I currently have. There is probably a better way.

Comment: @Hank, glad to hear that it's working well for you. In terms of implementing the search I am afraid I would be of little help as algorithms and code optimisation are not my forté; the async side of things is more up my alley. However there's a lot of folks on SO that are extremely knowledgeable on the topic, who will be able to provide some insight on implementing and/or optimising the search, so it's definitely worth raising this as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass in a cancellation token, from a CancellationTokenSource to the task and keep a count of the number of times you have changed text by incrementing a variable, you will be able to check this value and cancel the task, by calling token.Cancel(), and call a ThrowIfCancellationRequested which raises a OperationCancelled exception.

The continuation must be passed TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled for it to execute only when the cancellation is raised otherwise it will be raised when the other task has finished. 
(Code example to follow)

Comment: I have looked at some MSDN examples (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), now that I know what I'm looking for, just a little stuck on how to piece this altogether with the imcremental, could you piece together an example please.

Comment: I'm just trying to put something together. Its actually not as straightforward as I first thought as we dont want to kick off the task on each button click but rather need to widen the scope of the tasks up a level on to the  behaviour or form.  Whats the lifetime/scope of the behaviour?

Comment: It is searching for text matches in the cells of a datagrid. It basically populates an ObservableCollection with item objects it has found matches on. It takes a couple of seconds to run through 120,000 items.

Comment: This gets a bit more complex then as each time your text changes you will want to update the search, and not necessarily cancel your changes (as you may be re-entering the same value in the text field).   If you are updating out to an observable collection and this can be modified by multiple threads then this would need some thread synchornisation constructs around it, i.e. locking of some sort.  What is the purpose of the collection, you may be able to use a concurrent collection. Also if there is any looping some ParellelLinq may help.  Is this an auto suggestion feature?

Comment: At the moment while it searches I have a temporary ObservableCollection in which the items get placed, at the end of the task it copies over to another ObservableCollection which is bound to the vertical scrollbar of my DataGrid and displays markers to display positions of the matched items. This is the only place where the collection will be modified, short of when the popup is closed and the collection is cleared. This does not have an auto suggestion feature.

Comment: As far as looping ParallelLinq and use of a concurrent collection, not sure on these, I mean I don't think I'm familiar, is this to increase efficiency of the search process?